# 2 Managed Packages in 1 Dev Org

Tags: managed-package, appexchange

We have a Managed package, and we want to create another Managed Package extension in the same Dev org. Can I create 2 Managed Packages in 1 Dev org? If not, what are my options and do I have to pay Salesforce to increase the limit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot create two managed packages in one dev org, you can only have one namespace created per DE org.

Your options are to create another DE org and install the first managed package in there. Then, once you start to reference the first managed package in the new DE org, then that package becomes an extension of the first. Once you release your second managed package, subscribers would have to install the first package and then the second.

Comment: Thanks Phil. Are you sure about this? So you are saying there is no way I can have another Managed Package even if I`m ready to pay for another add on package? Just want to make sure I understand this correctly.

Comment: Yes, you can only create one managed package per developer org.

Comment: You can only develop one managed package in one DE org, there is a 1:1 relationship between the Packaging org (i.e. the DE org that is used to release the package from) and the Package.  I work for an ISV and I'm sure if there was a way, paid or otherwise, we'd know about it by now.

Comment: I should add, I'm referring to 1st generation managed packages, there may be other options with 2nd gen managed packages but is currently in beta i believe.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much Phil.

Answer (score 7):

Phil is correct for 1st gen packages.

2nd gen packages are indeed not out of beta yet. Notably, Salesforce hasn't fully documented exactly how 2GP will get connected to Publishing Console, Security Review, LMA, COA etc. But going by current info, here's basically how it would work once they go live:

- Your DE org will still "own" the namespace.
- You'd create a link from your Production org, which has a Dev Hub, to the DE org so that it "registers" the namespace and has permission to use it in 2GP.
- Your Dev Hub can now create scratch orgs with this namespace (this part is already GA).
- Your Dev Hub can now create packages with this namespace, and they can be multiple different packages. (beta)
- Different packages with the same namespace have some special rules on what they can/can't share with each other. (beta)

Comment: The "multiple packages" bit is for internal organization of your managed package. You can still only have one managed package per developer org. I don't think they've stated that this will be changing any time soon.

Comment: My understanding is that under 2GP it will be possible to release multiple independent or dependent packages with the same namespace, using DX. The packaging org will no longer be the source of truth for packaging.

Comment: Oh, that would be a nice addition. Handling so many different logins for all those dev orgs was a royal pain. We'll have to see how it works once it comes out of beta.

Comment: See this for example: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_access_modifier.htm A new access modifier that determines whether different packages in the same namespace can access the same Apex class.

Comment: 2GP is coming out of beta in the Winter '20 release.  See the release documentation [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_sfdx_packaging_2GP_GA.htm?edition=&impact=)